# Problem on Function Mapping

Tags: combinatorics, functions

Let $S = \{1, 2, 3,... m\}$, $m > 3$. Let $X_1......X_n$ be subsets of S each of size 3. Define a function f from S to the set of natural numbers as, f(i) is the number of sets  $X_j$ that contain the element i. That is $f(i)=\{j | i \in X_j\}$. Then
$\sum\limits_{i=1}^m f(i)$ is

(A) 3m
(B) 3n
(C) 2m + 1
(D) 2n + 1

My approach:

f(1) = $\binom{m-1}{2}$

f(2) = $\binom{m-1}{2}$

...

$\sum\limits_{i=1}^m f(i)=m \times \binom{m-1}{2}$

But above answer is not matching with any given options. What I've done wrong.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear to me! Is there any other information for sets $X_1...X_n$ except of that that they have only 3 elements from $S$?

Comment: @Emin that's the complete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing wrong is the following: the $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are just *some* arbitrary subsets of $S$ of size 3. But in your answer, you are assuming that the $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are *all* subsets of $S$ of size 3.

If you want to give it another try, stop reading at this point.

## Spolier Alert!

To compute the sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^m f(i)$, you tell for each $i\in S$ in how many $X_j$ they are. But as the $X_j$ are subsets of $S$, you end up checking $i\in X_j$ for every $1 \le i \le m$ and $1 \le j \le n$, so
$$
\sum\limits_{1\le i \le m} f(i)
=\sum\limits_{\substack{1\le i \le m\\1\le j\le n\\i \in X_j}} 1
=\sum\limits_{\substack{1\le j\le n}}
\sum\limits_{\substack{1\le i \le m\\i \in X_j}} 1
\overset{X_j\subseteq S}{=}
\sum\limits_{\substack{1\le j\le n}}
\underbrace{|X_j|}_{=3}
=
3\cdot n
$$